# Why do I have to declare a function within a closure access variables defined in the closure?

Tags: javascript, closures

Why do I have to declare a function within a closure to be able to access the variables in the closure? I expected that I would be able to define the function outside of the closure, but close around it, providing the variables it needed, but the variables are not available unless the function is actually defined within the closure.

http://jsfiddle.net/c5oba93a/1/

```
//reusable function defined outside of closure, I want to swap out myMethod within this function.
var reusableFunction = function () {
    //common code
    try {
        console.log(myVar);
        myMethod.call(this);
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
    //common code
};


var functOneForClosure = function () {
    console.log('functOne');
};
var functTwoForClosure = function () {
    console.log('functTwo');
};

//myMethod and myVar are undefined in reusableFunction
(function () {
    var myMethod = functOneForClosure;
    var myVar = 'variable in closure with functOne';
    return reusableFunction;
})()();
(function (myMethodIn) {
    var myMethod = myMethodIn;
    var myVar = 'variable in closure with functTwo';
    return reusableFunction;
})(functOneForClosure)();

//if the function is defined within the closure it behaves as expected.
var getReusableVersion =(function (myMethod) {
    var myVar = 'defining function within closure makes the difference';
    return function () {
        //common code
        try {
            console.log(myVar);
            myMethod.call(this);
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
        //common code
    };
});

getReusableVersion(functOneForClosure)();
```

Comment: A var declared inside a function is not 'visible' outside this function and gets cleared when the function has finished execution.

Comment: where do you see that happening @MartinErnst?

Comment: There are two IIFE defining `myVar` and `myMethod` inside and returning`reuasableFunction` which then gets executed. When the IIFE's return the vars get cleared because they are not passed to `reusableFunction`. Also the vars are not 'visible' at the 'place' where `reusableFunction` is defined.

Comment: essentially that is the question - since `reusableFunction`, `myMethod` and `myVar` are all visible within the IIFEs, why are `myMethod` and `myVar` not visible within `reusableFunction`?

Comment: Inside the IIFEs you just don't `define` but only `points to` `reusableFunction`. But a function can only reference variables that are visible where the function is `defined`.

Comment: I see - using the reference doesnt even create a closure since the function is not actually defined within the closing function... To get the expected behavior I'd have to explicitly change the scope of the method I am invoking `(function () {
        this.myMethod = functOneForClosure;
        this.myVar = 'variable in closure with functOne';
        return reusableFunction.call(this);
    })();`

Comment: Another way to say it is that the scope at invocation is always the scope at definition.

Comment: @pherris: No, `this` is not the scope, it's the *context* for a call - which is like an implicit parameter to which you pass an object. It won't work with the `var`s in your `reusableFunction`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@pherris According to your beforelast comment: That won't help. The `this` inside the IIFEs refers to  the `window` object and now you spam it with additional properties. But `myVar and myMethod` inside `reusableFunction` still are undefined, you have to use `this.myVar` and `this.myMethod` instead. Better than spamming the window is to pass the vars as arguments:

```
var reusableFunction = function (myVar, myMethod) {
    // no try/catch needed anymore
    console.log(myVar);
    if (typeof myMethod == 'function') myMethod.call(this);
    else console.log(myMethod);
};
```

Now there are two ways to invoke it with your IIFE.

The first returns the function from IIFE with arguments bound to it and executes it afterwards:

```
(function () {
    var myMethod = functOneForClosure;
    var myVar = 'variable in closure with functOne';

    // first argument of .bind() appears in the function as 'this',
    // the others appear as fixed arguments of the function
    return reusableFunction.bind(window, myVar, myMethod);
})()();
```

The second way invokes it inside the IIFE, so the invocation afterwards is removed:

```
(function () {
    var myMethod = functOneForClosure;
    var myVar = 'variable in closure with functOne';

    return reusableFunction(myVar, myMethod);

    // of course its possible to call on 'this', but that doesn't change anything:
    /* return reusableFunction.call(this, myVar, myMethod); */

})();
```

Comment: Great things about this exchange: scope vs context, window scope of IIFEs and a reminder about .bind() - thx!